# After opening activity i won't replace the layout with fragment but i got exception

Tags: java, android

this is how open my activity from another activity

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("result","result");
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
            finish();
```

this is my onactivityresult its works but crashs when want to change the fragment

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String result = bundle.getString("result");
            Log.d(Constants.TAG_FRAGMENT,"RESULT_OK: "+result);
            ZapisFragment zapisFragment = new ZapisFragment();
            manager.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left,
                    R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right)
                    .replace(
                            R.id.content_main,
                            zapisFragment)
                    .addToBackStack("tag")
                    .commit();
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Write your code if there's no result
            Log.d(Constants.TAG_FRAGMENT,"RESULT_CANCELED");

        }
    }
}//onActivityResult
```

}

but i get error in line of .commit(); this is what error it was

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: #########, PID: 16589
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {/###########}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3798)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3841)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:154)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1440)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1842)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1860)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:650)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:609)
                                                   at ru.prezident.ghazaryans.prezidentmed.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:720)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6490)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3794)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3841) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1440) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

and i can't find where is my mistake, need help , thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling `super.onActivityResult`, try after calling it :

```
@Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // other code
    }
```

or may be you are calling it using wrong **manager**, you should use it like this :

```
manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
manager.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left,
                    R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right)
                    .replace(
                            R.id.content_main,
                            zapisFragment)
// and so on...
```

Comment: Hi @Serg, which solution fixed your issue ?

Comment: i add super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); and it works